Updating OpenSSL 1.1.1 in Ubuntu 22.04.3
How to update openssl in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. The current version is openssl 3.0.2. But it have vulnerability. So I need to update to openssl 1.1.1.
The following are the vulnerability with openssl 3.0.2:
Path : /snap/core20/1950/usr/bin/openssl Reported version : 1.1.1f Fixed version : 1.1.1o https://cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2022-1292 http://www.nessus.org/u?9667f400 https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20220503.txt
